# Стек для web разработки на java

Tags: java

Посоветуйте какой стек сейчас популярен для web разработки на java, и с чего 
лучше начать учить.

Comment: За последние 15 лет ничего не изменилось - Spring, а начать нужно с изучения стандартов Java EE.

Answer (score 1):

Spring. Если с Java SE/EE все ок, то можно посмотреть в сторону книги "Pro Spring 5", на русском - "Spring 5 для профессионалов".

Answer (score 1):

Java 8,
Spring Framework (Spring Boot/MVC/Data JPA/Security),
Hibernate.
Видео в ру сегменте для старта есть достаточно.